# How can I ignore certain schemas with alembic --autogenerate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I have a library that's part of a bigger project. The library uses its own schema in a (PostgreSQL) database shared with the larger project.

I want to use `alembic revision --autogenerate` to only generate migrations for the library's schema and ignore changes to the tables in the main/default schema. Is there any option for doing this?

FWIW, I've tried the `include_schemas=False` parameter to context.configure in env.py, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems I can use `include_object` in conjunction with `include_schemas`

In `alembic/env.py`:

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table' and object.schema != MY_SCHEMA:
        return False

    return True

...
context.configure(..., include_object=include_object, ...)
```

Answer (score 14):

Based on Oin response, finally a method which ignores tables while running db revision --autogenerate

In alembic/env.py or migrations/env.py:

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if (type_ == "table" and object.schema == "exclude_from_migrations"):
        return False
    else:
       return True
```

In alembic/env.py or migrations/env.py:

```
def run_migrations_online():
   ....
   context.configure(connection=connection,
                  target_metadata=target_metadata,
                  include_object = include_object,
                  process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
                  **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)
   ...
```

Now in the tables that you want to ignore:

```
class MyClass(db.Model):
__tablename__='my_class'
__table_args__ = {"schema": "exclude_from_migrations"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `include_name`: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_name

This is a new hook added in alembic==1.5, and is the recommended way to filter out schemas during `autogenerate`:

*For the use case of omitting specific schemas from a target database when EnvironmentContext.configure.**include_schemas** is set to True, the schema attribute can be checked for each Table object passed to the hook, however it is much more efficient to filter on schemas before reflection of objects takes place using the EnvironmentContext.configure.**include_name** hook.*

Related discussion:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/650

Comment: Yeah, this actually is faster and less error-prone than the above answers. Glad alembic added this and thanks for adding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. Just ignore schemas by name during initiate before including objects.

```
def include_name(name, type_, parent_names):
    if type_ == "schema":
        return name not in settings.POSTGRES_IGNORE_SCHEMAS
    else:
        return True

def run_migrations_offline():
    context.configure(
        include_name=include_name,
        url=get_url(),
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        compare_type=True,
        include_schemas=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()
```