# Update database through migrations but not delete any table in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have a PostgreSQL Database of 10 tables, but in python("flask_sqlalchemy") I have created only 5 models and skipped other 5 tables as that are not needed now. But when I try to update model and run migrations other 5 tables get deleted.
Is it possible to skip or not delete 5 tables and update other tables?
I am using "flask_migrate" package to perform migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [include_object](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=include_object#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object) option to specify which tables you want Alembic to ignore. There is an example that is close to what you need in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342367/how-can-i-ignore-certain-schemas-with-alembic-autogenerate).

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't detect changes in other models

Comment: You probably didn't do it correctly. Update your question with what you did please.